# In what situation would you use Select without from?

Tags: sql-server, ado.net

I'm studing for an exman and I stumbled upon an answer to a question with this format:

```
    public DataTable SueldosHistoricosEmpleado (int idEmpleado)
{        
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection   (ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conexion"].ConnectionString);

          SqlDataAdapter da=null;   

            SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand(@"SELECT HistoricoSueldos WHERE idEmpleado=@id",conn);

             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", this.id);

             Try{    
                conn.Open();     
                  da=new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);      
                  Dataset ds=new Dataset();  
                    da.Fill(ds);
                      return ds.Tables[0]; 

                            }  
                             Catch(Exception)
                             {    return null;   }
```

I understand what the method does, the only issue I have is that in the select there is no from. It just select an entire table.
What is it doing exactly?

Thanks for clearing this up

Comment: I don't think this can work.

Comment: I thought the same thing, the thing that it's the answer. Maybe they made a mistake, either way I wanted to make sure

Comment: Do not take my word for it, wait for more responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is C#, the code will not compile because the language is case-sensitive (e.g. `Try` should be `try`).

If the code did compile, it will raise a SqlException because the SQL statement syntax is invalid (there is no `FROM` clause so the referenced column name can't be resolved). The exception handler will then catch the error and return value `null`.